# How to properly initialize lazy collection through entity?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I need to initialize collection via using entity by self. I mean, i can do it in Java such as below:
I would call the method from StatelesBean class.

So, how can i do it in php way? If anybody can write sample code, i would be appreciated.

```
@Transient
public void initialize(Collection collection, int levelCursor, int level)
{
    if (collection instanceof PersistentBag)
    {
        if (ObjectUtil.isNull(((PersistentBag)collection).getSession()))
            return;
        else
        {
            Iterator itr = ((Collection)collection).iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext())
            {
                if (levelCursor < level)
                    ((SuperEntity)itr.next()).initialize(levelCursor, level);
                else
                    itr.next();
            }
        }
    } else
    {
        Iterator itr = ((Collection)collection).iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext())
        {
            if (levelCursor < level)
                ((SuperEntity)itr.next()).initialize(levelCursor, level);
            else
                itr.next();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Searches for column and join column annotations for getter methods.
 * If found then tries to initialize childs
 * @param levelCursor
 * @param level
 */
@Transient
public void initialize(int levelCursor, int level)
{
    levelCursor++;

    Method[] methods = this.getClass().getMethods();

    Object obj = null;

    try
    {
        for (Method method : methods)
        {
            if (method.getAnnotation(JoinColumn.class) != null || method.getAnnotation(JoinTable.class) != null || method.getAnnotation(OneToMany.class) != null)
            {
                Object result = method.invoke(this, new Object[0]);
                if (result == null)
                    continue;

                if (result instanceof SuperEntity)
                {
                    if (levelCursor < level)
                        ((SuperEntity)result).initialize(levelCursor, level);
                } else if (result instanceof Collection)
                    initialize((Collection)result, levelCursor, level);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what you're trying to do? Btw, I'm not sure the Java example is helpful here. Some PHP context would be more useful.

Comment: Suppose that, we have User entity and ownedCars arrayCollection in it. And fetchType is LAZY, so when i get user entity record i may want to reach ownedCars collection. I want to initalize them such as user.initialize(1) {1 is deepLevel} or user.initialize(user.getOwnedCars())

Answer (score 1):

So, as I understand your task, you want to initialize the objects of your entitys collection when you retrieve them?

Doctrine loads your collection automagicaly, when you call for it.

So you could do it with a getter:

```
    class User
    {

        /**
         * OneToMany(targetEntity="Car", mappedBy="owner")
         */
        private $ownedCars;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->ownedCars = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        public function getOwnedCars($level)
        {
            // autoload collection
            foreach($this->ownedCars as $ownedCar)
            {
                $ownedCar->initialize($level);
            }

            return $this->ownedCars;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you and yes this is an approach that solved the lazy initialization. But actually, i want to solve this in reflection way, because I dont want to write that all entities which have arrayCollection. I prefer to generic solution as i mentioned on my question such as method on MappedSuperClass contains reflection.

Comment: Is it an option to implement the magic [__wakeup()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.wakeup) method in your target entity? It will be called when doctrine deserialize the object.